# Do subscribers increase video views?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Does the number of subscribers that you have affect the number of views that each video receives?

I didn't see an indication of such but I'm asking because that would be the natural idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they don't.

Subscribers are just another resource.  Views is Cash, and subscribers is a Progress Rating.

Comment: This can be tested using a Sponsor Eagle to get extra subscribers, but it's not exactly easy to setup so if someone comes across it, they can confirm that Subscribers don't increase views.

Answer (score 1):

Subs do not increase views. Although they may increase the length your video would be out for collecting views (or that might be linked to your Level) which gives you more time to collect views. They do, however, unlock Knowledge which CAN increase views better than the starting Knowledge you can use from the get go.